# how to run html5 container in winform application?

Tags: c#, .net, html, browser

My client does not have html5 compatible browsers deployed enterprise wide. Browser upgrade will happen sometime in future, presently all workstations have IE7 ( win xp).

For any new development we are looking at leveraging html 5 , that we can easily run in future html5 browsers without significant changes. But there is a challenge in deploying a html5 solution today due to lack of browser compatibility.

We are open to deploy our solution as a windows native application ( C#, winforms ) which can host a html5 browser control and run web solutions build for html 5.

Are there any c# winform level controls out there that may allow this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Ehm, sorry, but if you can install a new desktop application that holds a webbrowser control, can't you also install IE8?

Comment: Unfortunately NO. because it would replace IE 7 lots of other applications are compatible with. hence the delay in upgrades.....

Comment: That's why IE8 comes with a highly customisable compatibility mode.

Comment: upgrading the browser is not an option hence I am looking for a more tacticle solution. I am sure experts at the firm are evaluating options to upgrade to most recent IE version sooner than later. ( compatibility mode works for 90% cases but all ).

Answer (score 2):

According to this [site](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/148633/Web-Browser-Control-Winforms), this is impossible if the version of Internet Explorer installed is not capable of displaying the html5.

Comment: yeah the same link also talks about .Net Webkit. that aims to do something similar. I am looking at a more promising or tried solution if there is.